# Probability of a draw given 15 pairs of objects

Tags: probability, statistics

Given 15 pairs of objects, what is the probability that you will draw exactly one of your desired object if you were to take 3 out of the 30 total objects?  If possible, work this out by not using the complement of the probability.

Please give working :)

Answer (score 1):

We want to choose exactly $1$ of the $2$ "good" objects and exactly $2$ of the $28$ "bad" objects. Hence, we obtain:
$$
\frac{\binom{2}{1} \binom{28}{2}}{\binom{30}{3}} = \frac{27}{145}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  one way is to draw the pair first, then some other object.  How many positions are there for the two elements of the pair?